# install codeigniter on sub domain, going to error when put controller on subfolder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've installed my codeigniter on my subdomain: http://mt.domain.com and i've setup $config['base_url'] = 'http://mt.domain.com'.

I've user panel and admin panel, which is user panel controller already put on:
**application/controllers/User.php**, and this user panel work 100%.

But there is error for admin panel and login panel, which are already put on subfolder:
**application/controllers/staff/Login.php**

screenshoot:
[error login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V96y1.png)

so the problem is occurred, when i put controller on sub folder, example: **mt.domain.com/subfolder/admin**

How to solve this problem? thanks

this is my controller Login.php

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller{
 function __construct(){
  parent:: __construct();
  $this->load->model('m_admin');
  $this->load->helper('captcha');
  $this->load->library('encryption');
 }
 function index(){
  $this->load->view('admin/login/v_login');
 }
```

and this is my view's file on views/admin/login/v_login.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login - Bootstrap Admin Template</title>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> 
    
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/admin/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/admin/css/font-awesome.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/admin/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet');?>" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/admin/css/pages/signin.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
 
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 
 <div class="navbar-inner">
  
  <div class="container">
   
   <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </a>
   
   <a class="brand" >
    Login Admin MBill V.1.0    
   </a>  
   
   <div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
     <li class="">      
      <a href="https://mt.adrihost.com/" class="">
       <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
       Back to Homepage
      </a>
      
     </li>
    </ul>
    
   </div><!--/.nav-collapse --> 
 
  </div> <!-- /container -->
  
 </div> <!-- /navbar-inner -->
 
</div> <!-- /navbar -->



<div class="account-container">
 
 <div class="content clearfix">
  
  <form action="<?php echo base_url('staff/login/aksi_login');?>" method="post">
  
   <h1>Admin Login</h1>  
   
   <div class="login-fields">
    
    <p>Please provide your details</p>
    
    <div class="field">
     <label for="username">Username</label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" class="login username-field" />
    </div> <!-- /field -->
    
    <div class="field">
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="login password-field"/>
    </div> <!-- /password -->
    
   </div> <!-- /login-fields -->
   
   <div class="login-actions">
    
    <span class="login-checkbox">
     <input id="Field" name="Field" type="checkbox" class="field login-checkbox" value="First Choice" tabindex="4" />
     <label class="choice" for="Field">Keep me signed in</label>
    </span>
         
    <input type="submit" class="button btn btn-success btn-large" value="Sign In">
    
   </div> <!-- .actions -->
   
   
   
  </form>
  
 </div> <!-- /content -->
 
</div> <!-- /account-container -->



<div class="login-extra">
 <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
</div> <!-- /login-extra -->


<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="js/signin.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

the problem is on css file, which is need to be properly installed an assets folder on root. So i decided to put all css files on root. and then problem is solved.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use / to find the base directory in all assets
replace 'assets'/... to '/assets/...'
Example
Old :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

New :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And also put your assets folder on the root directory
Change all and you are done I think

Comment: the problem is only when i put my controller in subfolder, and the error is occured. the assets work for my controller application/controller/Login.php. But got and error with controller application/controller/staff/Login.php. I've changed all base directory, still doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome always bro